# Skiing questions: travel.SE or outdoors.SE?

Tags: discussion

Do skiing questions belong on Travel.SE or on Outdoors.SE? Or do they belong on both, depending on what exactly the question is?

At the time of writing (2012-10-28):

- Travel.SE has [11 questions tagged snow-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-sports).
- Outdoors.SE has [17 questions tagged skiing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing).

I propose we try to write down a policy together, and perhaps migrate some questions from Travel.SE to Outdoors.SE.

I've given a possible answer below, but it is not complete.

Triggered by [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10376/2509).

Answer (score 7):

On Travel.SE:

- Questions on how to get to ski resorts ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2480/2509))
- Questions on facilities at ski resorts ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3555/2509))

On Outdoors.SE:

- Questions on skiing where the primary focus is nature experience (e.g. skiing trips in the wild, ski mountaineering; [example](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/818/566))
- Questions on the skills required for skiing ([example on Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/898/566), [example on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10376/2509))
- Questions on equipment ([example on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4537/2509), [example on Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/691/566))

Not sure:

- Questions specifically about downhill skiing ([example on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10376/2509), [example on Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/898/566)).

Answer (score 5):

Much like any topic, where the nature of the question is travel related, it's travel.SE.

So for example, talking about travelling to see auroras = travel.  Asking about what causes them = science/astronomy - not travel.

However with travel and outdoors, there's always going to be some overlap, which makes it trickier.  Many people go on holiday to go skiing, so they consider it travel and therefore ask it on here.

I don't see any problems with most of the ones you've cited on travel.SE, aside from the one that was migrated today.  I notice that you actually linked to that one twice in your examples (both in the ones you think should be in outdoors, and the one you're not sure on).

Your [other one that looked dubious at first] about what to pack for a skiing trip - I first considered it very much outdoors, then noticed they weren't just asking about skiing equipment, they're asking about passport and ID stuff too, which makes it a bit more travel at least.  However sadly none of the answers have addressed this, making it a bit more outdoorsy - including the accepted one.  Others may have thoughts on this?

Comment: I just realised skiing may be on-topic not only here and on outdoor, but also on sports...

Comment: @gerrit - there's a sports now? (runs off to look)

Comment: Oh man I'm so tempted to try and become the resident cricket guru, I hardly get to watch any more now that I'm in Canada / travelling.

Answer (score -1):

I do not agree with the answer @gerrit gives to his own question. I think that travel is much more than just getting from a place A to a place B. For some people this is travel. In German we say "Der Weg ist das Ziel", which means "The way is the goal". However, for other people, traveling is only a way to the goal. Many people travel, i.e. they go from A to B to do a specific activity, at place B, such as sightseeing, hiking, skiing, relaxing, and so on.

Comment: What you say is true, however Stack Exchange sites are intentionally limited in scope to avoid off-topicness and to better focus their core auditory. This is arguably one of the strongest advantages of Stack Exchange sites that differentiates it from many online communities where "anything goes". Looks like you are relatively new to the community and it might take some time to get used to the peculiarities of the SE system. If you'd like to learn more about the SE network, a good idea might be to check [the SE blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/). You are always welcome in chat as well.

Comment: It is a good idea too limit the scope, especially when it come too broad topics like "travel". However, I notice that this is not too systematically done here. Hence my remark. There is some work to be done. Anyway, I see that this is a "beta" site. Then this kind of imperfection is acceptable.